# Salesforce certification exam Admin Vs Developer

Tags: certification

I Have 5 months of experience in a startup company i worked there Admin as well as Developer now i am looking for the Salesforce Certification so which exam will be good for me as a carrier aspect. kindly assist me.

Answer (score 2):

it is primarily a opinion base question. if you are good and like to write logic you can go for developer path but if you like drag and drop world you can go for administrator path.

[image]

Following video will help you to understand this in more details

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM5Th-ComR4

Reference URL : http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/developer-certification-in-progress.jsp

Answer (score 2):

I have also asked for same question and got answer as Admin ADM201 first and then go for Platform App Builder certification. Later go for your specialised area for Admin or Developer based on your taste.

Also it's not good to go with individual certification in one area. You should be have basic certification of Admin  & Dev and then advanced certification based on you interest, as Dev and Admin bonded very closely in salesforce daily activities.

Study Guide of Certification will help you to determine which area you are comfortable and which area you need to concentrate more.

Comment: Refer below link for similar question and its answer to it.

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/117557/29141

Also please find the Certification Study Plans link and more details related to it
http://certification.salesforce.com/

http://certification.salesforce.com/app-builders
http://certification.salesforce.com/administrators

Good luck & Prepare well.